# split on certain column when it is a url and has spaces

Tags: regex, awk, split

I have thousands of lines of data similar to

```
abc:1.35         (Johndoe 10-Oct-14): /usr/data/2013a/resources/fspecs/abstractbpweight/abstractbpweight.xml - Wed Aug 27 17:57:37 2014 33 13590770 33056 1 422 6367 234

efg:1.1         (Jane 12-Oct-14): /usr/data/2013a/resources/source data/abstractbpweight/file.xml - Tue Aug 26 17:57:37 2014 33 13590770 33056 1 422 6367 234
```

To get just the first column and the fourth column (url) into another file, I was using

```
awk '{print $1 $4}' file > smallerfile
```

Now the fourth column url sometimes has spaces and the entire path did not get captured for some cases. Also I suspect it might have other characters too (e.g. -,_ etc) and hence I wasnt sure if I can split using "-". How can I get just the first column and the fourth column in its entirety.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your normal lines (i.e. those without extra spaces in url) have always 17 fields:

```
awk '{printf "%s",$1;for(i=4;i<NF-12;i++)printf "%s%s",OFS,$i;if(NF)print ""}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
abc:1.35 /usr/data/2013a/resources/fspecs/abstractbpweight/abstractbpweight.xml
efg:1.1 /usr/data/2013a/resources/source data/abstractbpweight/file.xml
```

It prints first field, then field 4 and extra fields belonging to url which made total number of fields be greater than 17. This removes empty lines if you need them delete `if(NF)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `/\.xml/` to decide what to print

`awk '$4~/\.xml/{print $1,$4} $5~/\.xml/{print  $1,$4,$5}' file`

will produce output

```
abc:1.35 /usr/data/2013a/resources/fspecs/abstractbpweight/abstractbpweight.xml
efg:1.1 /usr/data/2013a/resources/source data/abstractbpweight/file.xml
```

what it does?

`$4~/\.xml/` checks if the pattern `.xml` is contained in 4th field, if yes print `$1` and `$4`

`$5~/\.xml/` checks if the pattern `.xml` is contained in 5th field, then print all the fields.

Comment: there is a space in second url (`source data`) this code does not preserve it. It is converted to `sourcedata`.

Comment: @Ashkan add a comma `,` in `print`. corrected in answer. Thank you :)

Comment: It doesnt always have .xml files. I should have specified in the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
awk -F[-:] '{ split($2,a," "); print $1 ":" a[1] $5 }' file
```

The idea is to use `-` and `:` as field separators to allow any number of spaces inside the parenthesis.

But indeed the path can contain hyphen too. So to prevent this you can use sed instead that will check the space and hyphen after the path:

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+)[^:]+:\s+(.+?)\s+-.*/\1 \t\2/' file
```